# Converting string to int (or something else), is there a prefered way?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Sometimes i wonder, when converting strings to other types, for example int32, is one way better than the other, or is it just a matter of taste?

```
Convert.ToInt32("123")
```

or

```
Int32.Parse("123")
```

or

Some other way?

**Not considering the case if it's not a valid int in this question.**

Comment: If you are not sure about the string , use `TryParse` which will help you know whether the string can be converted to an `int` or not

Comment: Depends on whether you want to know if the value can be converted. See also Parse / TryParse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse

Comment: TryParse is always the best. DO not use Pare. Parse throws exception.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting discussion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Convert.ToInt32** is actually implemented the following way...

```
int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

...which is the same as your stated alternative except it takes into account the culture settings. The **int.Parse** method is itself implemented the following way...

```
Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
```

...where Number is an internal class that you cannot call directly. The **Number.ParseInt32** method is marked with the following attribute...

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
```

...showing that it is implemented inside the CLR itself.

Answer (score 2):

Main difference between `Conver.ToInt32` and `Int32.Parse` is how the treat `null` strings. `Convert.ToInt32` returns default value in this case:

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)    
        return 0;

    return Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

I don't like that. I think only `"0"` should be parsed to `0`. This behavior initially was [designed for Visual Basic programmers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx):

> This is a set of conversion methods for programmers migrating from Visual Basic 6 to Visual Basic .NET that mirrored the behavior of the
>   existing Visual Basic 6 conversion methods. The assumption was that C#
>   programmers would be more comfortable with casting operators, whereas
>   Visual Basic had traditionally used conversion methods for type
>   conversion.

So, as non-VB programmer, I'd go with `Int32.Parse` and `Int32.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

When converting from string to int I always use int.TryParse. Because you are not always sure you can convert a string to an int. Like this:

```
string temp="222";
int intValue;
if(int.TryParse(temp,out intValue))
{
    //Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As V4Vendetta suggested it is better to use TryParse to avoid exceptions related to converting.

```
int result = 0;

a = "3";
string b = "b";
string c = "2147483648"; //int32 max value + 1

int.TryParse(a, out result); // returns true result=3
int.TryParse(b, out result); // returns false result=0
int.TryParse(c, out result); // returns false result=0
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I'm talking about already validated strings, or strings that should give an exception if not valid.

Comment: are you validating for min and max values?