# Avoiding try-catch by using tryparse instead of parse

Tags: c#, parsing, try-catch

In a lot of places in my code I have this:

```
try
{
    price = double.Parse(sPrice.Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch
{
    price  = 0;
}
```

I read somewhere that if the exception is thrown in the try block, it takes a lot of time being caught.

So, I'd like to use tryparse instead of parse, like this:

```
if (!double.TryParse(sPrice, out price))
{
     price  = 0;
}
```

Is this a good practice? Will it take less time?

Comment: You *could* benchmark it yourself. As for good practice, well. That's entirely subjective but I prefer tryparse-methods, myself. =)

Comment: Yes it will indeed save execution time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse v. TryParse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse)

Comment: You should only do this if failure is expected to happen sometimes, e.g. when parsing user-typed text. You should not do this when parsing stuff which is *supposed* to be correct. Otherwise you are hiding errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `TryParse` is faster.

However, this smells like a premature optimization to me, unless you expect `Parse` to be called in a tight loop with many invalid input strings.

You should choose not depending on speed but depending on requirements and what kind of data you expect to get. Also, consider another option: `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: How do you mean premature optimization?

Comment: How do you know it is too slow? :)
In most cases, overhead introduced by exception handling is negligible compared to rest of the processing so it makes no sense to optimize the code for speed. The readability/ease of maintenance are quite often better optimization goals, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Two benefits I feel of using `TryParse`

1. It is fast as compared to `try.. catch...`
2. You will always have value in your variable, either the one you want to assign or the default one. So you can use your variable directly once it is passed to TryParse