# I am getting the exception Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the above error from the following code

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> ListSms = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
ListSms.Add(int.Parse(sms.Sms_Nom));
```

the problem looks like some space include in the text i brought in Sms_Nom so this why I try to Parse it but it dosen't work !

any ideas ?
thanx

Comment: "so this why I try to Parse it" - what made you think that `int.Parse` would accept values with spaces? You need to get it into the right format *before* you parse it.

Comment: The parse failed. The value contained in `sms.Sms_Nom` could not be parsed to an `int`. How should we know why without seeing the value of `sms.Sms_Nom`? Use a debugger to find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = 0;
if (int.TryParse(sms.Sms_Nom, out value))
{
  ListSms.Add(value);              
}
```

Have a look at this question about [Parse v. TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse)

**Update - to remove spaces in beteween**

```
 if (int.TryParse(sms.Sms_Nom.ToCharArray()
             .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
             .Select(c => c.ToString())
             .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b), out value))
            {
                ListSms.Add(value);
            }
```

this will work for string like "2 2", which will make it "22" before .TryParse()

Comment: I guess that OP has spaces in the number like `"12 3"` and he want to parse it as `123`: _"problem looks like some space include in the text"_

Comment: One drawback of this solution is that if the `Sms_Nom` is not in a valid format the information will be lost. That is, to the list we will only add the `Sms_Nom`s that would be parsed by the `Parse` method anyway. We will not add `Sms_Nom`s that for instance contain a white space but are valid in any other respect.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Oh didn't saw that part :) updated now

Answer (score 0):

use trim before `int.Parse()`.

Also it's advisable to use `int.tryParse()` instead `int.prase()`.

Comment: Trim won't get rid of a space inside the text. You may need to use `String.Replace(" ", "")` method.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem looks like some space include in the text i brought in
>   `Sms_Nom`, so this why I try to `Parse` it but it dosen't work !

So you have a `sms.Sms_Nom` string like `"1 2 3"` which should be parsed to `123`?

If you have spaces in the text and you want to remove them, you can use this LINQ query which creates a new string from all non-space characters. Then use  `int.TryParse` to check if it's an `int`:

```
var noSpaces = sms.Sms_Nom.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
string smsNom_noSpace = new String(noSpaces.ToArray());
int sms_Nom;
bool isInt = int.TryParse(smsNom_noSpace, out sms_Nom);
if(isInt)
    ListSms.Add(sms_Nom);
```