# VB.Net Int32.TryParse Conversion Exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing, tryparse

I understand this might be considered a duplicate of this: [Parse v. TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse)

But, could anybody tell me why this code threw an exception when Tryparse is not supposed to throw any exceptions at all?

```
If Int32.TryParse(txtOrdLine.Text.Trim, txtOrdLine.Text) = False Then
```

The value entered in txtOrdLine was "1-4".

The exception was that it could not convert string "1-4" to type Integer. This is on a code behind for a ASP.Net 4.5 site if that makes a difference.

Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your second parameter has to be an integer type variable.

Comment: It is being converted automatically when it is a valid number so that is not the case. Besides, the error is from string to integer, not the other way around.

Comment: Set [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to point out problems like that in the code.

Comment: Hmm, no.  The [Int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) function wants that second parameter to be an integer.

Comment: Agree with Andrew and Lars.  What is this code trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring because the automatic conversion the second parameter from `String` to `Int32` is failing.

VB.Net is effectively re-writing your code as:

```
Dim temp as Int32
temp = Int32.Parse(txtOrdLine.Text) ' Exception here!
Int32.TryParse(txtOrdLine.Text.Trim, temp)
txtOrderLine.Text = temp.ToString()
```

You'll need to create a temporary `Int32` value and pass that into `Int32.TryParse()`

Comment: ...or just use a zero if you don't care about the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a check then you don't need a variable.

```
    If Not Int32.TryParse(txtOrdLine.Text.Trim, Nothing) Then
        'here if parse fails
    End If
```