# Cannot submit a form with empty TextBox (reverse validation and let it submit)

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a simple Windows Forms application with a form that has two TextBoxes to find postcode/suburb name:

1. Enter the suburb name
2. Enter the postcode

If the postcode (TextBox) has no value entered the form is hung up and it won't submit/return values. Tried a few things but still fails (FormatException was unhandled). Adding any int value it works fine.

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //DECLARE ARRAY
    string[] arrSuburbName = new string[5];
    int[] arrSuburbPC = new int[5];

    //POPULATESUBURB NAME ARRAY
    arrSuburbName[0] = "DEE WHY";
    arrSuburbName[1] = "SYDNEY";
    arrSuburbName[2] = "HURSTVILLE";
    arrSuburbName[3] = "BALMAIN";
    arrSuburbName[4] = "NORTH SYDNEY";

    //POPULATE POSTCODE ID ARRAY
    arrSuburbPC[0] = 2099;
    arrSuburbPC[1] = 2000;
    arrSuburbPC[2] = 2220;
    arrSuburbPC[3] = 2041;
    arrSuburbPC[4] = 2060;

    //VARIABLES
    string inputSuburb = "";
    int inputPostCode = 0;
    string msg = "";

    //INPUT
    inputSuburb = txtInputSuburb.Text.Trim();
    inputPostCode = int.Parse(txtInputPostCode.Text);


    //PROCESS
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSuburbPC.Length; i++)
    {
        if (inputSuburb.ToUpper() == arrSuburbName[i])
        {
            msg = "Postcode for " + arrSuburbName[i] + " is: " + arrSuburbPC[i];
            inputPostCode = 0;
            break; //EXIT THE LOOP
        }
        else if (inputPostCode == arrSuburbPC[i])
        {
            msg = "Postcode for " + arrSuburbName[i] + " is: " + arrSuburbPC[i];
            break; //EXIT THE LOOP
        }
        else
        {
            msg = "Postcode Not Found";
        }
    }

    //OUTPUT
    lblResult.Text = msg;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because there is no value within your `txtInputPostCode.Text` and you are trying to parse it, make a check before parsing whether the `textBox` has any value or not and then parse if it has some value.

Comment: what would you like to be the default value `inputPostCode` if it is empty? in such cases you need to use any conditional statement like @J.SMTBCJ15 answered and yes you cant parse a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Int.TryParse(...) instead of Int.Parse(...)?

[Parse v. TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse)

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
inputSuburb = txtInputSuburb.Text.Trim();
inputPostCode = int.Parse(txtInputPostCode.Text);
```

but in the UI screen you attached you gave **OR** so it can happen that postcode will be empty.

You need to change you logic in code. Things to consider:

1. What to do if post code is empty? -> this is your situation right now
2. What if user enter non-number like 'abcd'

Your logic should have some **validation**. Use *try catch* construction for example.

Maybe you should also consider user **NumericUpDown** control?

Comment: I am going to have to think about this some more after the comments / suggestions.

Any links on simple snippets to add some validation would be appreciated? Be cool if C# had something like "required".

1. Work out the logic

2. Test if either textbox has value (use one or the other)

3. If Postcode is empty parse value - validate += value

4. If Postcode has alphabetical character return messagebox/alert - validate

5. If Suburb has numerical character return messagebox/alert - validate

Comment: Q. try catch - something like this?

catch (InvalidCastException e)  
{  
    if (e.Data == null)  
    {  
        throw;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        // Take some action.  
    }  
 }

Comment: Yes, for example. The point is that you miss logic on how system should work when Postcode is present or absent.