# Int32.Parse vs Int32.TryParse

Tags: c#, input

People have been suggesting to use Int32.TryParse but I found out that in case of any string such as "4e",it would give me output 0(i would directly print my input),whereas Int32.Parse would give an Exception. Is  there a  side to using TryParse which I am not able to see? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't ignore the boolean return value.

Comment: S.a. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse

Answer (score 2):

`TryParse` and `Parse` should treat what is a valid number in the same way. The difference is the way they signal that the input was invalid. `Parse` will throw an exception, while `TryParse` returns a `boolean` which you need to manually handle.

```
if (!int.TryParse(input, out var result))
{
    Console.Write("NOK"); // Don't use result, it will have the default value of 0
}
else
{
    Console.Write($"OK {result}"); // Ok, reuslt has the parsed value of input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the boolean return value like this:

```
  string text1 = "x";
  int num1;
  bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
  if (res == false)
  {
      // String is not a number.
  }
```